# How to customize listform of "Pages" (document library) list

Tags: list-form, pages

Is there a way to customize the "Edit Properties" form of the pages list? It must be a deployable solution...

With "customize" I mean something like the ability to collaps a given part of parameters.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've done something *similar* by:

1) Creating a new Application page which uses a DataFormWebPart control to render a custom form. The Application page can be deployed via a WSP.

2) Customising the DataFormWebPart to show / hide certain fields, and expanding regions etc

3) Changing certain SharePoint links to point to the custom form. For example, adding / hiding items on the ECB menu.

You can initially create (1) using SharePoint Designer (insert a custom list edit form for you library) and then copy the markup into the Application page.

However, note that the original Edit form is still available, which you may not want. So a user who knows the URL can still get to the original form.